# How can I display all the rows using PHP with a 'while' loop?

Tags: php

I am trying to display row by row, but it shows this error:

> Undefined offset: 0

Here is my code:

```html
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "postgres";
    $password = "20152016";
    $db = "Projet";

    $con = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$password")
        or die ("Could not connect to server\n");
?>

<?php
    $query = "SELECT ST_ASGeoJSON(geometry) FROM poi where type='batiment'";
    $result = pg_query($con, $query);
    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $data = array();
        echo $data[0];
    }
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: The whole top of your code is irrelevant to your question. It boils down to the last 2 lines You create an empty array (`$data = array()`) and then echo the first item in that array (`echo $data[0];`). Since it is empty, $data[0] does not exist. That is why you get the undifined offset error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this piece of code:

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))  
{  
$data = array( );
echo $data[0];
}
```

To this:

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))  
{  
    foreach($row as $rslt)
        echo $rslt;
}
```

Comment: i will define this variable in javascript code but i can't @pakistanimoon can you help me please

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari: please do not use the quote device for decorative effect. The purpose of quote blocks is to hold quotes, and it is not to be used for ordinary paragraph text. Thanks.

Comment: <?php 
  $query = "SELECT ST_ASGeoJSON(geometry) FROM poi where type='batiment'";  
$result = pg_query($con, $query);
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))  
{  
    foreach($row as $rslt);

  var geojson_Point = 
  {
   "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
   },
   "geometry":
  
        echo $rslt;
  
  }  }?>
  ;

Comment: @halfer aye aye captain! X)

Comment: @sara there are many ways to access php code's output in javascript, easiest one is use ajax, hopefully u already know that. secondly u can creat a variable containing all the output and use that variable in javascript as var jsvariablename = '<?php echo $phpvariable; ?>'

Answer (score 1):

Your `$data` array is empty and its unnecessary so it cause undefined offset.

Change this

```
 while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))  
{  
$data = array( );
echo $data[0];
}
```

to this

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))  
{  
   foreach($row as $rc) { 
          echo $rc[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: but also he show me the error Undefined offset: 0

Comment: yes i am changing it but he show "Undefined offset: 0"

Comment: @sara you have successfuly connected to database? also your query runs perfectly ?

Comment: yes thanks the 2 answers can show the result

Comment: which is correct answer?? and what was the mistake @sara?

Comment: @Noman upvote! for being super fast! :D

Comment: Thanks @HawasKaPujaari :D